# VMWare Web Server Access

Tags: windows-server-2003, vmware-server

I need to stop the VMWare Web Server Access service, on a Windows Server2003 machine. I have admin rights on that machine. How do I see all running services and stop it?

Comment: * sigh * once again...VMWare is a company not a product, we can't answer you unless you let us know which of their ENORMOUS range of products you're talking about...

Comment: Look at the tags, hes talking about vmware-server, he propably means the tomcat server that allows the config access

Comment: This isn't even a VMware question. It boils down to "I need to stop a service on Windows Server 2003, where can I view and control the services on the server?"

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your tags I see you mean vmware-server and you want to shutdown the web access to it right?

Well if you go to your startmenu->allprograms->vmware-server or something in that manner you should see a menu for the tomcat server. This is the server process that runs the web access, from this menu you should also be able to shut it down...

If not, You can hit ctrl+alt+delete and go into task manager, then search for tomcat, I think that should do it.

I've been using vmware-server for a long time but have been running it only on Debian (Linux) machines for a few years, although I used to run it on Windows, Linux machines just don't eat up all the precious resourses that I could use for a VM.

Comment: VMWare server reached EOS on 6/30.2011. You should consider migrating your VMs to a supported and available platform. http://www.vmware.com/support/policies/lifecycle/general/index.html